# How to add active class to list and parent list in drop down

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Please help me to resolve this problem.
Below is my navigation bar. I used Bootstrap 3 for navigation bar.
How to add active class to current list anchor tag and also add active class to parent list anchor tag in drop down menu.
Below is my html, css, and js file.
please guide me to resolve my problem.

```js
//dropdown menu
            $('.nav_bar_custom .drop_menu1').hover(function() {
                $(this).children('ul').stop(true, false, true).slideToggle(300);
            });
            

var path = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop();
if ( path == '' ) {
    path = 'index.php';
}
var target = $('nav .nav_bar_custom li a[href="'+path+'"]');
target.addClass('active_menu');
```

```css
.navigation{
     background: #304269;
     
}

.nav li a{ color: #fff;}
nav li{ 
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.nav li .drop_menu2 li{
  display: block;
  
  float: none;
}

nav ul li a.active_menu {
    color: #0BADEE;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="navigation clearfix" id="navigation">

    <nav>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right nav_bar_custom">
         <li>
            <a href="index.php">Home</a>
         </li>
         <li class="drop_menu1">
            <a href="training.php">Training</a>
          <ul class="drop_menu2" id="drop_menuT" style="display: none;">
             <li>
                 <a href="basic.php">Basic</a>
             </li>
             <li>
                 <a href="intermediate.php">Intermediate</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                 <a href="advance.php">Advance</a>
              </li>
           </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a href="blog.php">Blog</a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
          </li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
 </div>
 
 
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: when you post snippet just make sure don't post snippet with error

Comment: Your question is not clear, the snippet also does not work. Kindly update your question with correct code.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below script:

```
<script>
    var path = 'basic'; //Dynamic value using PHP
    var target = $("a[href$='"+path+"']");
    target.addClass('active_menu');
    target.parent().parent().parent().find('a:first').addClass('active_menu');
</script>
```